# Java 6 Source backward-compatibility and SQL

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, backwards-compatibility

My understanding is that in order to maintain source-compatibility, Java never introduces new methods to public interfaces, as that breaks existing clients implementing the interfaces.  [Java Release notes](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/compatibility.html#source) states

> In general, the policy is as follows,
>   except for any incompatibilities
>   listed further below:
>
> - Maintenance releases (such as 1.4.1,
>     1.4.2) do not introduce any new language features or APIs. They will
>     maintain source-compatibility with
>     each other.
> - Functionality releases and major
>     releases (such as 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 5.0)
>     maintain upwards but not downwards
>     source-compatibility.

Yet, the packages `java.sql` and `javax.sql` continue to evolve and introduce many incompatible changes.  For example, I noticed the following incompatible changes (introduced in Java 6):

- [`java.sql.Statement`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) extends `java.sql.Wrapper`, requiring new two new methods.
- [`java.sql.Statement`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) introduces 3 new methods
- [`java.sql.PreparedStatement`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) introduces 19 new methods!
- [`java.sql.ResultSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) introduces 48 new methods!

Do you know how and why these methods got added?  Is `java.sql` being treated differently from the rest of the platform?  Do you know of the discussion/JSR around these additions?

Comment: Adding methods does not break upwards compatibility, only downwards (which is allowed for major releases, like Java 6).

Comment: But the `java.sql` types are interfaces, not classes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**I got the following reply from a Sun Developer**

The general evolution policy for APIs in the JDK for feature releases like JDK 7 is

1. Don't break binary compatibility (as defined in JLSv3 chapter 13)
2. Avoid introducing source incompatibilities
3. Manage behavioral compatibility change

(For more, much more than you'd like to read on different kinds of compatibility see

["Kinds of Compatibility: Source, Binary, and Behavioral"](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/kinds_of_compatibility)
and
["Compatibly Evolving BigDecimal"](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/compatibly_evolving_bigdecimal)

Adding methods to interfaces is binary *compatible* but *source* incompatible, so it is not commonly done.  Generally, the more widely implemented an interface is, the less likely we are to add methods to it.  The JDBC area is an exception to this policy and uses looser upgrade rules, but that does cause real issues when people want to upgrade to a new JDK release.

Comment: Should that be "does *not* cause real issues"?

Answer (score 4):

Note that adding new methods only break source compatibility, already compiled implementations of `Statement` or `ResultSet` in a JDBC driver will continue to run on a newer JDK. Only when you try to call a new method you will get a `NoSuchMethodError`.

Comment: Correct.  That's why I restricted the question to source compatibility!

Comment: This is not correct. It breaks all drivers implemented for Java 5. See my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238252/how-to-make-jdbc-driver-work-in-java-5-6

Comment: @Zhang the problem in the referenced question is about binary downwards compatibility; i.e.. using Java 6 JDK while targeting Java 5 JDK.  Java never promised that!

Answer (score 1):

They probably assume that database driver vendors that implement those methods are keeping up-to-date with new Java runtimes, and that it's better to introduce useful new methods and temporarily break compatibility.

Of course, they could've designed it better so that breaking compatibility wouldn't be necessary…

Answer (score 1):

Sun never guarantees source compatibility between releases, only binary compatibility. The most common example is that source code that contains 'assert' or 'enum' identifiers will not compile under JDK 1.4 (for assert) or 1.5+ (for enum), but existing .class files will still run under those newer JVMs.

You can try using the -source flag to compile older .java files under newer JVMs but you may still run into problems if you're relying on jvm classes that have changed.

Comment: Not quite true.  I attached the policy for source compatibility in the question.  They are more lenient with breaking source compatibility than binary compatibility; but they usually document these changes.  `java.sql` changes aren't documented in the release notes.