# How do I build a Java project with Java 6 against Java 1.4 libraries?

Tags: java, macos, maven

I've got a project that was originally written for Java 1.4, but I only have Java 6 on my Mac and I cannot install Java 1.4.

Normally, I'd use a line like this to compile:

```
javac -source=1.4 -target=1.4 MyClass.java
```

However, `MyClass.java` implements the `java.sql.ResultSet` interface, which added several new methods in Java 6, so I get compile errors like:

```
MyClass is not abstract and does not override abstract method
updateNClob(java.lang.String,java.io.Reader) in java.sql.ResultSet
```

I cannot simply implement the missing methods because many use generics, which are not available in Java 1.4.

It seems a solution would be to obtain and compile against the Java 1.4 JARs. So, I've got a few questions:

1. Is there a better way?
2. How do I specify to my Java 1.6 `javac` that I'd like to use the 1.4 JARs instead of the Java 6 JARs?
3. Will this even work, and if so, will the project run on Java 1.4 as well as Java 6?
4. How do I do this in Maven?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261497/java-6-source-backward-compatibility-and-sql for JDBC API incompatibility between Java 1.4 and 6. Why can't you install Java 1.4 ? It should be as easy as un-zipping a file and setting JAVA_HOME to the right value.

Comment: Java 1.4 is not available for Snow Leopard, unfortunately.

Comment: @Jonathan: your lucky, for this use you can simply extract the JRE for *another* platform, since you *only* need the `rt.jar` for the class definitions. Keep using the current compiler with the `-source` and `-target` switches and use `-bootclasspath` to point to the `rt.jar` of the 1.4 release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your situation seems to be quite contrived. I'll try to simplify matters. At first, I am going to ignore your question about Maven.

So let me first state some facts:

`-source=1.4` means: Dear compiler, please accept only *language constructs* --- not library features --- which were available with javac of JDK 1.4.

`-target=1.4` means: Dear compiler, please write class files in a binary file format which is compatible with a JRE 1.4.

I gather that you are interested in load-time compatibility with JDK 1.4, i.e. you want that the class files produced in your setup can be loaded by JDK 1.4. Is that right?

Do you also want to support source compatibility? I.e. do you want to allow others to compile your code on a JDK 1.4?

If the answer to the last question is yes, I would try to install JDK 1.4 on OS X. It supports multiple installed JDKs. So I am pretty sure it is possible. If that is no option use:

```
-source=1.4 -target=1.4 -bootclasspath=[path/to/1.4.jar]
```

Note, do not use -Xbootclasspath. This changes the boot classpath of the jvm executing javac.

If the answer to the above question is no. You can dispose of `-source=1.4` allowing you to use generics and other Java 5 enhancement in your code. But you still have to provide binary compatibility by using:

```
-target=1.4  -bootclasspath=[path/to/1.4.jar]
```

Another option would be to use [Retroweaver](http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/).

After re-reading your question, I'd like add that you have to get hold of JDK 1.4 variant of the jdbc class files. Otherwise you'll run into the compiler errors you've shown in your question.

Comment: Thanks, that looks great. I'll try it. I really wish this situation *were* contrived :).

Comment: Worked perfectly. I managed to wrestle it into a Maven configuration also. Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear, that you've been successful.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are a JDBC vendor, it is unwise to implement interfaces like this one.

Consider using a [proxy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#newProxyInstance%28java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.Class%5B%5D,%20java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler%29) to maintain compatibility across JVM versions.

---

Migrating to a proxy is accomplished as follows. Consider this `ResultSet` implementation:

```
public class ResultSetFoo implements ResultSet {

  public String getString(int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    return "foobar";
  }

  // other Java 1.4 methods
```

This would be changed so no classes implement `ResultSet`:

```
public class ResultBar {

  public String getString(int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    return "foobar";
  }

  // other method signatures matching the 1.4 ResultSet, as before
```

You would then need to build a mapping of methods between the two types at runtime (a primitive form of duck-typing:)

```
  private static final Map RESULT_SET_DUCK = initResultSet();

  private static Map initResultSet() {
    Map map = new HashMap();
    Method[] methods = ResultSet.class.getMethods();
    for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
      try {
        Method match =
            ResultBar.class.getMethod(methods[i].getName(),
                methods[i].getParameterTypes());
        map.put(methods[i], match);
      } catch (SecurityException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // OK; not supported in 1.4
      }
    }
    return map;
  }
```

This allows you to invoke the `ResultBar` type by proxy:

```
  /** Create a java.sql.ResultSet proxy */
  public static ResultSet proxy(final ResultBar duck) {
    class Handler implements InvocationHandler {
      public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
          throws Throwable {
        Method proxiedMethod = (Method) RESULT_SET_DUCK.get(method);
        if (proxiedMethod == null) {
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException("TODO: method detail");
        } else {
          return invoke(proxiedMethod, duck, args);
        }
      }

      private Object invoke(Method m, Object target, Object[] args)
          throws Throwable {
        try {
          return m.invoke(target, args);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
          throw e.getCause();
        }
      }
    }

    return (ResultSet) Proxy.newProxyInstance(null, RSET, new Handler());
  }
```

Such implementations should allow code compiled in one JVM to be used in future JVMs even if new methods are added. *Existing method signatures are unlikely to change because it is one thing to make database vendors do some work; something else to make all API consumers change.*

You may need to change how class instances are created. You can no longer use a constructor directly:

```
ResultSet nonPortable = new ResultSetFoo();
//becomes...
ResultSet portable = proxy(new ResultBar());
```

If you're already employing a factory/builder/etc. pattern this bit is easy.

Although reflection is relatively cheap in the latest JVMs it is less so in older versions; this may have a detrimental effect on performance.

Comment: Believe me, I would love to pull all of that out. However, this project is legacy code, and it would require significant refactoring to do that, unless I've missed something with the Proxy class?

Comment: @Jonathan - I've elaborated on the cost/benefit trade-off of the proxy approach to this problem. This isn't the only way to do this, but it does tend to be one of the easier ones. _A more efficient approach that comes to mind involves custom ClassLoaders and bytecode transformations._

Answer (score 2):

> How do I specify to my Java 1.6 javac that I'd like to use the 1.4 JARs instead of the Java 6 JARs?

In Win. & *nix it would be by specifying the `bootclasspath` option.  See [javac: Cross-Compilation Options](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-options) for more details.

Comment: `bootclasspath` is not a `-X` option. Only the `/p`, `/a` and `/` variants are. In fact the Java 7 `javac` *warns* when you use `-target` for any version < 7 *without* using an appropriate `-bootclasspath` argument as well.

Comment: I thought something looked odd there.  Edited.  Thanks for the update re the Java 7 compiler.