# Programing with Eclipse for Java 6 and 7

Tags: java, eclipse, java-7, java-6

How to setup Eclipse executions environments and projects to be developed for both JAVA 6 and JAVA 7 JREs?

I'm asking this because not all programs that are developed to run over JAVA 6 will run in JAVA 7.

In this situation for example:

I need to use a JAVA API `interface`, and the JAVA 6 version of this interface is:

```
public interface Foo {
    int getValue();
}
```

But, the JAVA 7 version of this `interface` is:

```
public interface Foo {
    int getValue();
    int getNewValue();
}
```

Now, if I code my program like this:

```
public class FooImp implements Foo {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

This will run work fine on JRE 6. But, if I run it over JRE 7 it will not work, because the `Foo` interface requires the operation `getNewValue` to be implemented.

In this case, what is the best solution, using Eclipse, to code my program and ensure that it will run over JRE 6 and 7? How should I configure the execution environments and run the tests?

Note: At this moment, I'm working like this:

1. I code my program over JDK 6, to ensure that I'm not using any resourses of JDK 7 that doest exists in JDK 6.
2. I run the first test over JRE 6.
3. Then, it export my project and run it over JRE 7.

Note 2: Searching specifically about the `java.sql.ResultSet` problem, I found this question:
[Java 6 Source backward-compatibility and SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261497/java-6-source-backward-compatibility-and-sql)

Now I see that, this problem is common with JDBC, the sourcecode compability is broken with frequency. So, I think that there is no much to discuss here. Thanks all for the answers and the effort.

Comment: Which exact interface from the Java API are you using? Normally, Oracle doesn't add methods to interfaces in the standard API, to avoid compatibility problems exactly like you describe.

Comment: What is the problem to add 'getNewValue();' to your implementation class? Java won't kill if you added additional methos.

Comment: The interface `java.sql.ResultSet` had this two operations added:
`<T> T getObject( int columnIndex, Class<T> type )` and `<T> T getObject( String columnLabel, Class<T> type )`

Comment: @JoseRenato: Don't use `Foo` example when your problem is with `java.sql.ResultSet`. You'll get much better help...

Comment: @reporter I think you didnt understood the problem. Adding a new method is not the problem. The problem is, at the programing time, to know that a new operation was added on the interface. Imagine that you use 1000 diferent API interfaces, over diferent projects. The JAVA compability should ensure that a program that runs over JAVA 6 will work fine over JAVA 7. Dont you agree with that?

Comment: @jlordo I didnt put the ResultSet interface directly in the question because I figured that with the abstraction would be easier to focus on the problem, that is the compatibility that was broken. Like Jesper said: "Oracle doesn't add methods to interfaces in the standard API, to avoid compatibility problems...".

Comment: I don't get what this has to do with eclipse.

Comment: @Jose I did understand your situation and agree with you. But you cannot prevent it. If the difference between two versions too big you won't have a choice to converting the code for the new version. That is the fate of a developer who would paid for. It was the same situation when Sun made a cut between Java 1.4 and Java 5, or the hardware industry decided to let die the floppy disc.

Comment: @djechlin As I'm working with Eclipse I figured that someone had the same problem and created a solution using the environments configurations for example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's an elegant way to do this, but the following could work.

1. Reorganize and refactor your codebase into two parts:

   - the part that needs to work in the the Java 6 version of your codebase, and
   - the other code that is specific to the Java 7 version.
     (This is likely to involve creating some Java interfaces with Java 6 and Java 7 specific implementation classes.)
2. Put the Java 6 and Java 7 code into separate Eclipse Java projects.  Set the Eclipse project preferences to select the appropriate Java compliance level for each project; e.g. "Project > Properties > Java Compiler" ...
3. If you haven't already done so, further refactor the code so that the Java 6 and Java 7 specific classes are dynamically loaded by the core; e.g. using `Class.forName(...)`

This should allow you to develop the Java 6 and Java 7 parts in the same Eclipse workspace.

You should also be able to use "Run > Run Configurations" and/or "Run > Debug Configurations" to create launchers for Java 6 and Java 7 for in-Eclipse testing.

---

Note: I've not tried this myself.  Please let us know if it works.

Comment: I didnt understand the 3rd step. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: What don't you understand?  How to use `Class.forName()` ?